# Adding a sub-menu to a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how to add a new submenu for a custom post type in creating a wordpress plugin.
What I have done for now, I've created a custom post type called 'funds'.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wnm_add_funds' );
function  wnm_add_funds() {
register_post_type('wnm_funds',
    array(
        'labels'        => array(
                                'name'              => __( 'Funds' ),
                                'add_new'           => __( 'Add New Fund' ),
                                'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Fund' ),
                                'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Fund' )),
        'public'        => true,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'menu_position' => 100
    )
);
```

}

This code adds a custom post type called 'Funds' and under it is two submenus ('funds','add new fund'). What I would like to do is to add new submenu under funds. Example I would like to add 'Fund Settings', so under funds there will be (funds,add new fund,fund settings).

how would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities
I don't know if the capability is set right for your cause, but this will work

```
<?php
add_submenu_page(
    'edit.php?post_type=wnm_funds',
    'Fund Settings', /*page title*/
    'Settings', /*menu title*/
    'manage_options', /*roles and capabiliyt needed*/
    'wnm_fund_set',
    'CALLBACK_FUNCTION_NAME' /*replace with your own function*/
);
```

To add settings/options to the page I recommend the [settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)
A good (and bit long) tutorial how to use this: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/

Comment: @CHiRiLo I think you want to create settings? I recommend the settigns API, see my updated answer.

Comment: yeah. but what if i may add a metabox. who knows maybe someone wants to do that also.

Comment: The question should be ''what''(function) do you want to do not ''how''(technique) . Out of that question follows ''how'' you want to build that. So what do you want to make? And how would a metabox be better then a settings? It will be very hard to do.

Comment: if i merge custom post type with sub_menu_page then add new option is not show in left side of admin panel.

Comment: @Urocks if this is a problem please open a new question.